# Making an if statement that allows user input if condition in value is false

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of cells that I need to be equal to the value from another cell if certain conditions are met or if the conditions are not met allow user input. I need to do this without deleting the if statement when the user input is put in this cell. So for example in cell Ex(where x is the number of that cell) if conditions a & b are met then Ex = K(x-1); if the conditions are not met then allow user input.

So far I've tired using an if statement right in the cell and using a Macro. For the if statement in the cell I tried to make it return a "" if the conditions are not met. Obviously this didn't work as when the user put in the input the if statement is deleted. I also tried to make a Macro but I'm unfamiliar with VBA and I keep getting an error.

This is the if statement I put in cell E2 and then copy pasted in for the whole column:

```
IF(AND(K1<>0,K1<>"Actual finish"),K1,"")
```

And this is the Macro I tried to make:

```
(1)Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)  
(2)    Sheets("Main Menu").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
(3)End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("K:K").Value <> 0 And (Range("K:K").Value <> "Actual finish") Then 
    Range("F:F") = Range("K:K").Value
End Sub
```

Please note the first three lines are a different Macro from the one I'm trying to make. I included it in because I'm not sure if this syntax is proper for VBA.

Any ideas for how to solve this problem? I'm open to any ideas. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure I understand what you are looking for, but here is my approach:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False                'unlock all cells initially
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count   'iterate through column "f"
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 11)) And Cells(i, 11).Value <> 0 Then
            Cells(i, 6).Locked = True               'lock cells that satisfy condition in column "k"
        Else
            Cells(i, 6).Locked = False              'unlock cells that do not satisfy condition "k"
        End If
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Protect                             'protect to keep locked cells from editing
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim targetVal As Variant
    If Target.Column = 11 Then                      'we only care about changes in column "k"
        targetVal = Target.Value
        If IsNumeric(Evaluate(Target.Value)) And Evaluate(Target.Value) <> 0 Then  'condition
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect
            Target.Offset(0, -5).Value = targetVal  'here the formula is removed and value inserted
            Target.Offset(0, -5).Locked = True      'lock as condition satisfied
            ActiveSheet.Protect
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect
            Target.Offset(0, -5).Formula = "=IF(AND(K" & Target.Row & "<>0,K" & Target.Row & "<>""Actual finish""),K" & Target.Row & ","""")"
            'inserted formula as this is what you intended? should display empty cell
            Target.Offset(0, -5).Locked = False     'can be edited, but edit will clear formula
            'although formula is removed, if the condition is satisfied in the future, value in "k" will be inserted
            ActiveSheet.Protect
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I don't know of a way to not over-write a formula when you type a new value in the cell, but VBA can keep track of it through the "change listener". Anyway, a short walk-thru of what the above code does:

1) We keep the user from changing contents of cells with satisfied condition, so we use the protect property. We first need to unlock all cells and lock only cells that do not satisfy the condition.

2) We listen for changes in the column "K", and if any changes are triggered, we change the contents of the cell in column "F" and lock or unlock based on condition being satisfied in column "K".

My answer may not fully answer the question as I may not have completely understood it, but I hope this acts as a starting point at the least. Good luck!